# Dashboard: Not enough privileges to access Microsoft CRM object

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have shared a non-system dashboard with a manager user with "Read" privileges. This dashboard shows the other users activities. But when the manager opens the dashboard, he can see the dashboard components but he can't see the data. Each component displays the message You don't have enough privileges to accesses this CRM object.

I added him to the teams and gave him the same security roles of the users for which the dashboard displays the data but still nothing appears. 
His BU is different and not even a parent of these user's BUs. Could this be the problem ? What if i can't change the BU, can I solve this in any way ?

Edit:

The manager user has full organizational access to the Activity entity and he can see all the activities under "Activities" tab, but still he can't see it within the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CRM is clearly pointing out he issue: missing privileges. When two users are placed in "sister" BUs with a structure that looks like this:

```
   PARENT BU

BU1        BU2
User1      User2
```

There are some alternatives for the users to see each other's records:

1. They have Organization-level READ access to the entity (anything less cuts off any record which isn't part of the branch of the BUs tree starting with the user's BU)
2. The record is shared by one user to the other
3. [Not 100% sure because I never tried this approach] They are part of the same team *and* the records to be seen belong to the team itself (i.e. the Owner of the record is the team)

If by any change you can consider upgrading, CRM 2013 offers Access Teams to spread access to records with less encumbrance.

EDIT: I'll add another verification you can do: if the shared Dashboard points to Personal Views, they must be shared too because the CRM won't do it automatically. Views can be shared via **Advanced Find -> Saved Views**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the manager already has organization level access to Activity entity and he can see the Activities under "Activities" section, but they are not seen within the dashboard. I can't find an explanation for that.

Comment: So, if the manager goes to Activities section and selects the same view used in the dashboard, records show up ?

Comment: I think you spotted the problem. I just realized that he can't see the Saved View in Advanced find for Activities. I guess i'll look for ways to share the Saved View.

Comment: I was adding this very tidbit to the answer :) Personal Views must be shared along (the CRM doesn't include necessary related records when sharing)

Comment: Just tried and it solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer.